# Javapoet superclass generic

Tags: java, android, generics, javapoet

Anyone know how I can do the following using javapoet

```
public class MyClassGenerated extends MyMapper<OtherClass>{

}
```

My code of generation:

```
TypeSpec generateClass() {
    return classBuilder("MyClassGenerated")
         .addModifiers(PUBLIC)
         .superclass(???????????????)
         .build();
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `ParameterizedTypeName` class allows you to specify generic type arguments when declaring the super class. For instance, if your `MyClassGenerated` class is a subclass of the `MyMapper` class, you can set a generic type parameter of `MyMapper` like so:

```
TypeSpec classSpec = classBuilder("MyClassGenerated")
     .addModifiers(PUBLIC)
     .superclass(ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(MyMapper.class),  
                                           ClassName.get(OtherClass.class)))
     .build();
```

This will generate a `TypeSpec` object that is equivalent to the following class:

```
public class MyClassGenerated extends MyMapper<OtherClass> { }
```

While not specified in the question, note that you can set any number of generic type arguments by simply adding them in the **correct order** to the `ParameterizedTypeName.get` call:

```
ParameterizedTypeName.get( 
    ClassName.get(SuperClass.class),
    ClassName.get(TypeArgumentA.class),
    ClassName.get(TypeArgumentB.class),
    ClassName.get(TypeArgumentC.class)
); // equivalent to SuperClass<TypeArgumentA, TypeArgumentB, TypeArgumentC>
```

For more information about the `ParameterizedTypeName.get()` method, see the documentation [here](https://square.github.io/javapoet/1.x/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/ParameterizedTypeName.html#get-com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName-com.squareup.javapoet.TypeName...-) or the **"$T for Types"** section of the JavaPoet [GitHub page](https://github.com/square/javapoet).

Comment: You can also do `ParameterizedTypeName.get(MyMapper.class, OtherClass.class)`, it seems.